# Operator overloading polymorphism returning generic collection

Tags: c#, generics, polymorphism, operator-overloading, abstract-class

I want to overload the + operator for adding segments together to form a Path.
I've defined a Path where T is Segment and contains a List (where naturally T is Segment). Segment is an abstract base class for various types of Segment i.e. LineSegment

I have an overloaded method Connected which checks that the segments have a common end point. I'd like to define the overload for 2 Segments in the abstract Segment class and then for different types i.e. Segment and LineSegment within the respective derived classes.

```
public static Path<T> operator +(Segment s1, Segment s2)
{
    if (s1.Connected(s2))
    {
        List<Segment> slist = new List<Segment>();
        slist.Add(s1);
        slist.Add(s2);
        Path<T> p = new Path<T>(slist);
        return p;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

@Jon

So essentially...

I'm trying to replace the following code (path1 is a Path, Segments is a List where T is Segment).

```
Path<T> path1 = new Path<T>(s1);
path1.Segments.Add(s2);
```

with

```
Path<T> path1 = s1 + s2;
```

The problem is that with  the code does not compile.

Comment: And what's the problem? BTW: your aren't checking your input values against nullability, may fail at execution.

Comment: You still did not explain what is the problem. Does your current code work? If not, what *does* it do (compile errors, exceptions, …)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since C# doesn't support generic operators, I think there is no simple way to do this. But I can imagine several ways to make it work:

1. Don't do this. As Jon suggested, you could always return a `Path<Segment>`, even if you add, say, two `LineSegment`s. I don't like this “solution”, because it could mean you would have to use casts all over the place.
2. Add the operator to every type that inherits from `Segment`. This means repeating code, but I think it's the best option here. For example, the operator for `LineSegment` would look like this:

   ```
   public static Path<LineSegment> operator +(LineSegment s1, LineSegment s2)
   ```
3. Don't add two segments together, but instead add them to an empty path. If you do this, it would be probably best if you made `Path` immutable:

   ```
   var path = Path<LineSegment>.Empty + lineSegment1 + lineSegment2;
   ```
4. Use a variant of the [curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern):

   ```
   class SegmentBase<T> where T : SegmentBase<T>
   {
       public static Path<T> operator +(SegmentBase<T> s1, SegmentBase<T> s2)
       {
           return new Path<T>(new List<T> { (T)s1, (T)s2 });
       }
   }

   class LineSegment : SegmentBase<LineSegment>
   { }
   ```

   If you do this, you don't have any repetition, but it feels like a hack and it could complicate your inheritance hierarchy a lot (you can't inherit from a class that specifies `T`). I don't like this solution.

Comment: Thanks, better understood now. I don't have too many so 2 the best option. To be honest i could have chosen that way in the beginning but the child in me wanted to know the ideal approach.

var and dynamic seem to pop up a lot...am i missing out by not knowing anything about these? I only really know up to .NET 3.0

Comment: `var` doesn't actually change your code. It simplifies your code, so that you don't have to spell out your types (I'm ignoring anonymous types, because they're not relevant here). `dynamic` could be useful if you have variables with some compile-time type, but you want to use an operator based on their runtime-time type. For example with `Segment s1 = new LineSegment(), s2 = new LineSegment();`, the expression `s1 + s2` would execute the + operator of `Segment`. If you wanted to execute the operator of `LineSegment`, you could use `(dynamic)s1 + s2`. But I don't think that's very useful here.